# Manipulate string to drop columns on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm trying to manipulate a list (type: string) to use that list to drop some columns from a dataframe.
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lnzf.png)

The list is from a dataframe that I created a condition to return columns whose sums of all values ​​are zero:

Selecting the columns with sum = 0

```
condicao_CO8 = (ex8_centro_oeste.sum(axis = 0) == 0)
condicao_CO8 = condicao_CO8[condicao_CO8 == True]
condicao_CO8.to_csv('D:\Programas\CO_8.csv')
```

Importing the dataframe and turning it into a list:

```
CO8 = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Programas\CO_8.csv',
                 delimiter=','
                 )
CO8.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'Nulos'}, inplace = True)
CO8.rename(columns={'0': 'Info'}, inplace = True)
CO8.drop(columns = ['Info'], inplace = True)
CO8.columns
```

Images from the list:
[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKq8I.png)

Some itens from the list:

```
0                                          ABI - LETRAS
1                                 ADMINISTRAÇÃO PÚBLICA
2                                             AGRONOMIA
3                                             ALIMENTOS
4                                          ARQUIVOLOGIA
5                                  AUTOMAÇÃO INDUSTRIAL
6                                           BIOMEDICINA
7                                         BIOTECNOLOGIA
8                                   CIÊNCIAS - BIOLOGIA
9                                    CIÊNCIAS - QUÍMICA
10                                    CIÊNCIAS AGRÁRIAS
11                                  CIÊNCIAS BIOLÓGICAS
12                    CIÊNCIAS BIOLÓGICAS E CONSERVAÇÃO
13                               CIÊNCIAS DA COMPUTAÇÃO
14                                  CIÊNCIAS ECONÔMICAS
```

My goal is to transform the list so that I can drop the columns from that.

Transforming this list into this:
`"ABI - LETRAS", "ADMINISTRAÇÃO PÚBLICA", "AGRONOMIA", "ALIMENTOS", "ARQUIVOLOGIA", "AUTOMAÇÃO INDUSTRIAL"...`

for this I made the following code (unsuccessful)

`list_CO8 = ('\",\" '.join(CO8['Nulos'].apply(str.upper).tolist()))`

Please, can anyone help me?

I'm trying to get:

```
list = "ABI - LETRAS", "ADMINISTRAÇÃO PÚBLICA", "AGRONOMIA", "ALIMENTOS", "ARQUIVOLOGIA", "AUTOMAÇÃO INDUSTRIAL"...
```

To make:
`ex8_centro_oeste.drop(columns=[list])`

Dataset link: [Link for Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wL_mTongvBUhhTit5CAZvLxQtWBQzNKY/view?usp=sharing) (8kb)

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to do.  What is your input data, type?  What is the expected output (data, type)?

Comment: So sorry about that!
I'm trying to use that list to drop columns from a dataframe
This list is the columns name from a dataframe, i want drop columns that have the names in that list

Comment: I'll try to improve the question

Comment: oh that's easy: `df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]], columns=list("abc")); drop_cols = ["a", "b"]; cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in drop_cols]; df2 = df[cols]`

Comment: very nice solution, but i don't have the ["a","b"] columns name, i need to make that list that I mentioned before, to drop the selected columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your question properly only now. I deleted my previous answer. You want to drop all the columns that sums to zero, if I am not mistaken.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("./centro-oeste.csv")

import numpy as np
data.columns[np.sum(data) == 0] # data is the dataframe
# It out puts a list that you can use.
```

Comment: It didn't work for me =/;

```ex8_centro_oeste[np.sum(ex8_centro_oeste) == 0]```;

Error message:;

Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: It should be 'ex8_centro_oeste.columns', it is not just 'ex8_centro_oeste'